# Cannot update document using the NodeJS MongoDB driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a document in a Mongo database using the MongoDB NodeJS Driver. Here's the code:

```js
/**
 * Find a document with the specified filter and update it's data.
 * @param {string} collectionName The name of the collection to perform the operation in.
 * @param {object} filter The filter to find the document with.
 * @param {object} update The data to update the document with.
 * @param {object} options Optional settings. Refer to http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#updateOne
 * @returns {Promise<object|mongodb.MongoError>} A promise that resolves with the result object or rejects with a MongoError.
 */
const updateDocument = (collectionName, filter, update, options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    // collection.updateOne(filter, update, options, (error, result) => {
    //   // Resolve promise with result if error is null
    //   // Else reject promise with error
    //   return resolve(result) ? error == null : reject(error);
    // });
    collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, (error, result) => {
      // Resolve promise with result if error is null
      // Else reject promise with error
      return resolve(result) ? error == null : reject(error);
    });
  });
};
```

```js
db.updateDocument('homepage-settings', { setting: setting }, { value: value }, { upsert: true }).then((result) => {
        resolve(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
});
```

However, the result is undefined and the document is not updated and no new document is created

Comment: can you tell what kind of JSON you are passing to `db.updateDocument` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try like this?

1. List item

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne

```
   db.members.updateOne(
       { _id: 1 },
       [
          { $set: { status: "Modified", comments: [ "$misc1", "$misc2" ], lastUpdate: "$$NOW" } },
          { $unset: [ "misc1", "misc2" ] }
       ]
    )
```

Comment: This solution worked. I was missing the '$set' operator. Thanks!